# Behaviour of enumitem \setlist

Tags: errors, lists, enumitem

I have a package which creates some lists using `enumitem`.  The standard way to change list parameters globally is to use `\setlist`, but this sometimes produces errors if the list is a custom one. Here's a minimal document.

In the code below, assume that the custom list `test` is defined in the package, i.e., the end user of the package doesn't see the `\newlist` and `\setlist` commands. They would assume, therefore that they could use `\setlist[test]{nosep}` to globally set the list spacing  the `test` list. But this command fails with an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% assume this code is in a package
\newlist{test}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[test]{resume,leftmargin=*,label=(\arabic*)}
% end package code
% Now a user wants to adjust the list properties
\setlist[test]{nosep} % This doesn't work \setlist* is needed
%\setlist*[test]{nosep] % works and makes sense because it adds to list
%\setlist[test,1]{nosep} % But why does this work?

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
\item This is an item
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

There are two ways around this problem: 1) use `\setlist*` or 2) use `\setlist[test,1]`, i.e. add an explicit level.  Both options are not what an average user would expect to do.

### Questions

- Why does `\setlist[test]` fail and `\setlist[test,1]` work?
- Is there a way around this, so that I don't need to instruct users how to set list properties explicitly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Why does `\setlist[test]` fail and `\setlist[test,1]` work?

At its heart `\setlist[<arg>]` saves the settings passed to it to `\enit@@<slightly modified version of 'arg'>` with a `\def`.

Hence `\setlist[test]` overwrites an earlier `\setlist[test]`, since they both save to the same macro `\enit@@test`. But `\setlist[test,1]` does not overwrite what `\setlist[test]` did because it saves to `\enit@@testi`.

Your example then fails because `\setlist[test]{nosep}` removes the earlier definition and in particular the `label` definition leaving your new `test` environment without a label.

I didn't realise it before and I wasn't even aware of `\setlist*`, but now it seems to me that `\setlist*` is more natural and should be the go-to command for changing list settings. But I doubt a lot of people feel the same or even know about `\setlist*`, so that might not be an option.

#### Hang on, why does an innocent `\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}` not cause these errors?

`enumerate` is special because it is defined in the LaTeX kernel. Its label definitions are normally set in the document class, so you can't run into trouble with `\setlist[enumerate]` overwriting `enumitem` settings. Your `test` on the other hand is a clean sheet for LaTeX and so it needs a label definition.

#### Aha! Why don't we just define a default counter as well?

Indeed

```
\newcounter{testi}
\renewcommand\thetesti{\arabic{testi}}
\def\labeltesti{(\thetesti)}
\newlist{test}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[test]{resume,leftmargin=*,label=(\arabic*)}
```

would make the error go away if `\setlist[test]{nosep}` is used later on. But on closer inspection we find that that would only save `\setlist[test]{label=(\arabic*)}`. We would also have to set up `resume,leftmargin=*` ourselves. But those two can't be set up as easily as `label=(\arabic*)`. You would end up giving away the clean interface of `enumitem` in your package.

#### Is there a way around this?

My conclusion from these investigations is that I would try to educate users to use `\setlist*` instead of `\setlist`. Sorry.

It is possible to make a definition like `\setlist[test]{label=(\arabic*)}` `\setlist` proof, but more complex beasts like `\setlist[test]{resume,leftmargin=*,label=(\arabic*)}` would require a lot of extra legwork that is probably not worth it in the end (if it is possible at all, I did not check if I could get something like `resume` off the ground).

Comment: +1 for a well researched answer

Comment: Thanks moewe, that's what I suspected. But educating users is the worst.  :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I feel your pain. I assume you will have to document your `text` somewhere. At least for the rare few that read the documentation you can mention that `\setlist*` is the way. And if you are lucky not many people will actually think they can use `\setlist` on your environment.